# Prove Taylor expansion converges to $f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ fulfilling $|x-x_0|<{1\over M}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

**Is a single piece data incorrect? How can I know?**

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$, and let $C,M >0$ such that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\le CM^n n!, \forall x\in I, n\in \Bbb{N}$. Prove that for all $x_0\in I$, Taylor expansion around $x_0$ of $f$ converges to $f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ fulfilling $|x-x_0|<{1\over M}$.

If the data is wrong and $|f^{(n+1)}(x)|\le CM^n n!$ instead of $|f^{(n)}(x)|\le CM^n n!$, then let us look at Lagrange remainder(with the aforementioned $x,x_0$): $|R_n(x,x_0)|=|{f^{(n+1)}(c)\over (n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}|\le {CM^n\cdot n!\cdot(x-x_0)^{n+1}\over (n+1)!}={CM^n\cdot(x-x_0)^{n+1}\over (n+1)}<{CM^n\over (n+1)\cdot M^{n+1}}={C\over (n+1)\cdot M}\to 0.$

If the data is correct, I am really lost. I tried different remainder but it wouldn't work. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data given we get 
$$|R_n(x,x_0)| \leq \left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x)}{(n+1)!} (x - x_0)^{n+1}\right| \leq C\; (M\: \left|x - x_0\right|)^{n+1} \rightarrow 0 $$
for $|x - x_0| < \frac{1}{M}$.

Comment: But it is sort of like that: $\le |{CM^{n+1}(n+1)!\over (n+1)!} \cdot (x-x_0)^{n+1}|=    |CM^{n+1}\cdot (x-x_0)^{n+1}|<|CM^{n+1}\cdot {1\over M^{n+1}}|=C$ , isn't it?

Comment: Note however, that  $M |x - x_0|$ is some number which is smaller than $1$, hence its $n$th powers converge to $0$. If you apply the inequality $|x - x_0| M < 1$ directly, you are losing these $n$th powers and then the convergence cannot be detected as you noticed.

Comment: I just got it. Thank you.